# SOAP PHP is converting '<' to '&lt;'

Tags: php, xml, soap

Our SOAP request doesn't work because it seems that SOAP is converting our XML string into `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://some-test-url/xxx.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => true) );
    $soapparams = array (
        "UserName" => 'uname',
        "Password" => 'pword',
        "GroupID" => 1,
        "xmlstring" => '
        <![CDATA[
         <DocumentElement>
          <tbl>
            <var1>Q</var1>
            <var2>W</var2>
            <var3>E</var3>
          </tbl>  
        </DocumentElement>
        ]]>
        '
    );

    $response = $client->__soapCall('functionHere', array($soapparams));

$raw_request_header = $client->__getLastRequestHeaders();
$raw_request_body = $client->__getLastRequest();
$raw_response_body =  $client->__getLastResponse();

echo "<br /><br />Raw Request: ";
    echo "<code>";
    print htmlentities($raw_request_body);
    echo "</code>";
```

Im getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:functionHere>
            <ns1:UserName>uname</ns1:UserName>
            <ns1:Password>pword</ns1:Password>
            <ns1:GroupID>1</ns1:GroupID>
            <ns1:xmlstring>
                 &lt;![CDATA[
                 &lt;DocumentElement&gt;
                 &lt;tbl&gt;
                 &lt;var1&gt;Q&lt;/var1&gt;
                 &lt;var2&gt;W&lt;/var2&gt;
                 &lt;var3&gt;E&lt;/var3&gt;
                 &lt;/tbl&gt; 
                 &lt;/DocumentElement&gt;
                 ]]&gt;
             </ns1:xmlstring>
        </ns1:functionHere>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I prevent this to happen? I hope someone can help us with this.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: "Something like this", or "exactly like this"? I ask, because your example doesn't have the `DocumentElement` that shows in your example, nor the other parts of the SOAP request. Please give a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to guess which bits you left out.

Comment: @IMSoP question updated.